# Axios catches error then something throws the error again

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have this method:

service

```js
const errorData = {"message":"Error", "data": []};

list(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      resolve(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      resolve(errorData)
    });
  })
},
```

module store

```js
 state: {
    list: []
 },
 getters: {
        list: state => state.list,
 },
 mutations: {
    LIST(state, payload) {
       state.list = payload || [];
    },
 }
actions: {
   list({ commit }) {
     commit('LIST', []);

     return service
          .list('api/list')
          .then((list) => {
           commit('LIST', list);
           });
    },
}
```

list component

```js
this.$store.dispatch(`module/store/list`).then(() => {
     setTimeout(() => {
         var message = this.$store.getters['module/list'].message;
         this.$refs.inform.open('Error', message).then(() => {
             this.$router.push ({ path: "/" });
         });
     }, 1000);
})
```

Note: response.data from successful API call return an object with the same structure as errorData.

When I turn off the server where it calls the API methods, Axios catches the error if there are any, but something throws an error and halts the app's current operation "**net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**". I don't know where to catch this. I've tried appending catches on all methods using Axios related to this but then I couldn't catch the error. It should stop when the error is initially caught by Axios without stopping the app's operation.

I'd really appreciate any advice that can be given to resolve this problem of mine. Thank you.

Comment: axios return a promise by default, is there a reason to wrap it again inside a promise?

Comment: @RajaSekar I am following some code standard :)

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: As pointed out in the duplicate, you cannot stop the browser from logging the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. I am curious as to why you think this stops your application though. How are you using `list()`? What is it that you want to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: @Phil oh, so the browser logging the error is unavoidable. Thank you for clearing that one for me. I'm using list() from the module store, the code in my question is like, the global caller of get methods in my main service file.  As for my application stopping, after the error is logged in the browser console it's supposed to return a message back to the list and show it in a pop up message, but it doesn't. The page is blank and the the list is not rendered on the screen. I edited my question to clarify this :D

Comment: Please show where and how you're calling `list()`

Comment: @Phil hi, I added it in the question

Comment: So `list` is actually `service.list()`? Does `commit('LIST', list)` not execute? Where do you dispatch the `list` action?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I forgot to add list to the dispatch call. It is executed in this part `this.$store.dispatch(`module/store/list`)`

Comment: So what is it that's not executing? How are you determining the application has stopped?

Comment: `getters: { list: state => state.list, }`  just, why? What's the point of a getter that only returns the state property of the same name?

Comment: @Phil the function can execute without any problem if the server is okay, I just wanted to catch the net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in case the server is down. What I mean by the application stopping is when the error is thrown, the rendering of the list is halted when it is supposed to not do anything, just display empty since the data from errorData is []. The ones not executing are the following processes should the error appear. About the getter that only returns the state property of the same name, I'm supposed to follow some code standard hehe.

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry if I can't really relay my problem very well, English is still difficult for me.

Comment: That's the second time you've mentioned code standards that are anything but standard

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't resolve with an error. I assume that the code that calls the list method doesn't expect an error as the promise result, does it?

In case of error, the promise must be rejected, or you might want to catch the error and resolve with a default value, but resolving with the error doesn't make so much sense.

You can also simplify your code like this:

```
list(url) {
  return axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  }).catch((error) => {
    return { items: [] }; // <--- default value
  });
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and the  net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is still there and the operation stops.

Answer (score 0):

**Check database connection first**

**Try this**

```
async list(url){
  try {
    return await axios.get(url);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('This is error:->', e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, unfortunately this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
catch(error => {
        if (!error.response) {
            // network error
            this.errorStatus = 'Error: Network Error';
        } else {
            this.errorStatus = error.response.data.message;
        }
      })
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, but the error still persists and stops the app's current operation.

Comment: Can I know why your app operation is stopping? Because you can catch network error using my code then rest of the thing you will have to handle in that network error block.

Comment: That's what I would like to know. I don't know where it is coming from, that's why I want to catch it in any way possible.